# Is there a way to extend the display of the Ubuntu splash screen (Plymouth)?

Tags: plymouth

So I wonder if Plymouth can extend it's display by a determined time.

I know that this could delay boot time but I just want to find out this since is impossible to get this from the web and reading the documentation top to bottom is really time consuming to just find out that because is not intended for then this the feature doesn't even exist.